# Do men feel threatened by intelligent women?

Tags: psychology, sexuality, gender

I found this posted in multiple news sites

> The findings, to be published in the November edition of ‘Personality and Social Psychology Bulletin’, concluded that men find the propect [sic] of dating intelligent women intimidating.

--[The Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/science/new-study-says-men-find-dating-intelligent-women-intimidating-a6700861.html)

Does the study have those conclusions? Is the study reputable/reliable?

Comment: What about man dating intelligent man, women dating intelligent women, and women dating intelligent men? If we're trying to see one viewpoint, it's worth checking all the other - otherwise we might get biased results; the answer might not be "men are(n't) intimidated by intelligent women), but "people are(n't) intimidated by intelligent partners".

I am completely ignoring the fact that we haven't defined what "intelligent" means, how we measure it, and when someone becomes "intelligent"(and whether it's relative to other person or not).

For me, the question is extremely vague.

Comment: @MatthewRock it requires a larger and more expensive study. They might not have had the funds and they might have picked the "side" which they suspected had most signal...

Comment: Another problem with the study is that they're not looking at dating intelligent women, but at men dating women who are MORE intelligent than they are.  Which is going to be a problem for anyone who's a little insecure, whether it's intelligence, athletic ability, salary, or whatever.

Comment: Is your question only about the validity of that specific study? Or are you actually interested in the question of whether or not men might tend to be intimidated by more intelligent women?

Comment: @user2338816 I'm interested in the accuracy of the media I'm linking to, since that's what's being shared on social media. The media in question points to a specific new study, so there's that. However other studies can offer additional insights, for example: if the study is supported by stronger evidence, then the media is inaccurate in claiming this is a new finding, and i'd like to know that. If previous studies contradict the study that is also interesting. In all cases, though, the claim is that this comes from a specific study and that's what the question is about.

Comment: Good clarification; thanks. In that case, the article does mostly fairly reflect the study. **However**, the study isn't a great one to base the article on. As the study notes, a motivation for it was "To illustrate 
these processes...", processes that were suggested by previous more detailed studies (rather than to generate significant new knowledge). As such, previous studies would likely be better subjects. The subject study mostly just added a few new data points matching some existing expectations. Scientifically, it resulted in little except suggestions for deeper future research.

Comment: @MatthewRock - if there are scientific studies, they'd have to look at those aspects in order to draw any conclusions about the original concept in question.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

[This is the study](http://static1.squarespace.com/static/504114b1e4b0b97fe5a520af/t/55f0c6f6e4b04cec7f2e15ba/1441842934394/ParkInPressPSPB.pdf) the article mentions.

## Does the study have those conclusions?

Not really. The experimental results could equally be explained by a simpler conclusion, that people are less likely to ask others out when they feel disappointed, deflated or embarrassed by something (in this case, the public revelation of a poor test result). The researchers acknowledge that such an explanation is potentially valid and supported by prior research on "affective experience", and acknowledge this as a limitation.

It's also just one study, on about 100 U.S. psychology undergraduates, with a systemic bias excluding more intelligent students. It therefore can't be generalized without being replicated on other populations.

Here's an example of the kind of target used by the study:

> Seventy-three male undergraduates (M<sub>age</sub> = 18.95) participated in a “Study of Interpersonal Attitudes” in exchange for psychology course credit.

Age, field of study and personal maturity are confounding factors on psychological behavior. As such, the news reporting by "The Independent" is incorrect and misleading.

## Is the study reputable/reliable?

While the study is "serious science", is being peer-reviewed (or is in pre-print) and is quite interesting, the methodology has systematic bias against intelligent men, and the conclusions are not supported by the experiment set-up: the study merely shows that embarrassing or diminishing people in front of a potential date makes them feel a bit more antagonistic towards her. Likewise, it shows that flattering people in front of a potential date makes them feel more sympathetic and likely to ask them out. As reported, it does not measure anything else.

### Systematic bias

The study in question consists in letting participants take a math test, and then be told that their result was average.

> After a few minutes, the experimenter returned with the 
>   “graded” tests and announced their scores while handing 
>   back the tests. Participants always got 12/20 questions 
>   correct

At the end of the experiment, they were asked whether they believed the results and were discarded if they did not. This is a clear systematic bias because it excludes all candidates that are smart enough to expect a nearly perfect score and know that they can't possibly have an average result.

> [P]articipants 
>   responded to the following questions in written form: “What 
>   do you think this experiment was about? Was there anything 
>   odd or suspicious about this experiment? If yes, what?” 
>   Responses were later coded for whether participants 
>   mentioned (a) that their partner was not real or part of the 
>   study or (b) thought their test score was fake. Participants 
>   who reported suspicion on one or more of these items were 
>   excluded from analyses.

In fact, it excluded 10% of the participants.

> **Participants and Procedure**
>   Ninety male undergraduates participated in a “Study of 
>   Interpersonal Attitudes” in exchange for psychology course 
>   credit. Nine participants were excluded because they were 
>   suspicious of the confederate or did not believe the test 
>   feedback; the final sample consisted of 81 participants 
>   (M<sub>age</sub> = 18.81).

### Validity

First an experiment is set up where the fake results are given in a separate room from the potential date. In this case, performing *worse* than the date predicts more likelihood to ask the partner out or find them attractive.

Secondly another experiment is set up so that the fake results are given in front of the potential date. In this case, performing *better* than the date predicts more likelihood to ask the partner out or find them attractive.

I don't see how that supports that "men are threatened by intelligent women". It simply shows the obvious result that when someone's ego is boosted by good results they are more optimistic and when their ego is deflated they become timid.

The authors themselves admit to that, although they simply dismiss this as a "limitation".

> Previous research suggests that when people interact with 
>   a potential partner in a live context (e.g., spatially near 
>   context), they rely primarily on their affective experience—
>   positive or negative—to determine their attraction toward 
>   the target (Eastwick et al., 2014). In addition, research on 
>   SEM suggests that people experience negative feelings 
>   (e.g., jealousy) when they are outperformed in a self-
>   relevant domain (Salovey & Rodin, 1984). Together, these 
>   two strands of research suggest that men who interacted with 
>   a female confederate in the near condition may have felt 
>   badly when they were outperformed in a self-relevant domain 
>   such as intelligence, and these feelings shaped their evaluations of the confederate. Although we did not measure feelings of jealousy in the present studies, we did assess self-rated 
>   masculinity, which produced mixed results.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34861/discussion-on-answer-by-sklivvz-do-men-feel-threatened-by-intelligent-women).

Comment: Complaints about mods also deleted. Take them to meta, chat or Stack Overflow Inc.

Comment: Removing those who can identify what is being tested is not systematic bias - indeed, it's quite the opposite, it's attempting to remove bias due to "demand characteristics", as subjects who figure out what is being tested are likely to react differently than they would if they didn't figure it out. And a finding need not be conclusive in order to be a legitimate finding. The study found what The Independent, etc, said. If they failed to note that "more study is required", that doesn't mean that the claim that the study found it is faulty.

Comment: I agree that it's not the best way to deal with the issue. But that fact, itself, doesn't invalidate the findings in any way. Not only is the removal of 10% of participants from one of the six studies not enough to suggest systematic bias, but leaving them IN the data would be systematic bias, since those participants knew the data was fake or the situation was fake, and thus their actions wouldn't be representative of those who didn't know this. But mostly, I'm going to point to a simple phrase: "peer reviewed". Experts in the field consider this to be valid.

Comment: @Sklivvz - so you're saying that, as a skeptic, you'll take your own opinion over a peer-reviewed study? While you shouldn't be taking their results as gospel without replication, there's nothing disreputable about the study on the standards used within the field. And not only did the study make clear that it was only a preliminary result, and thus needed further study and replication, but even The Independent made a point to say "While the authors behind the study caution that more experimentation may be needed to confirm the conclusion..."

Comment: As for "removing people based on (presumably) intelligence" - that's not what they did. They couldn't use data from people who figured out what they were testing, because it would contaminate the data, and then you WOULD reject the result as nonsense. They chose a well-recognised and accepted method of dealing with subjects who figure out what's being tested, and they made clear that they did it. And yes, they used college students - which, again, they made clear, and it's also a common approach for the first stage of experimentation on issues like this.

Comment: @Sklivvz - do you have a source for the assertion that it's a poor one-sided study plagued with obvious mistakes, or are they merely your opinion? Note that I'm not suggesting that it would be wrong for a skeptic to accept the conclusion. But the question that you, yourself, posed can only reasonably be answered in the affirmative - the study did find that result (and the authors clearly identify the limitations), and the claims in the news article accurately reflect the study's findings.

Comment: Your answer is nothing more than an opinion-filled criticism of the standards currently at play within the field of psychological research. You make many claims without any expert evidence. For example, you assert that their method of dealing with demand characteristics (although you don't use that terminology) creates systematic bias because it filters out intelligent people - you have no evidence that those who figure out the hypothesis are intelligent, and instead are just making assumptions based on your own biases. If this answer weren't by a mod, it would be flagged as needing evidence.

Comment: @GlenO please move further comments to the chat (I will ask moderators to clean this up), but note that I will not repeat myself further, as it seems pointless. Note that 2 mods already reviewed this answer so the accusation that it's somewhat being favored is risible.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, **yes**, the study has that conclusion.

The study, as found [here](http://static1.squarespace.com/static/504114b1e4b0b97fe5a520af/t/55f0c6f6e4b04cec7f2e15ba/1441842934394/ParkInPressPSPB.pdf), states:

> Focusing on men’s romantic evaluations in the present research, ...[snip]... in psychologically near situations (i.e., real, spatially near, face-to-face interactions), men distanced themselves and showed less interest in women who outsmarted them.

It then notes that

> Preliminary evidence suggested that feelings of diminished masculinity accounted for men’s decreased attraction toward women who outperformed them in the live interaction context, although further research is needed to confirm the robustness of these findings.

Of course, the term "intimidated" does not strictly appear here; however, "show[ing] less interest" and having "feelings of diminished masculinity" can reasonably be interpreted as a sense of intimidation in the context of dating.

Tthe study is not definitive by any means. However, the description as given by the news sites is a reasonable one, and reasonably accurately describes the study and its findings as given by the authors and published in a peer-reviewed journal.

Comment: "Men" in the context of the conclusion means "university students". There is no attempt within the study to have a statistically valid sample of men.